# Setting css style for the first div load

Tags: jquery, chat

I have some links like :

```
<a href="#" class="chat_user">User</a>
```

When i click on one of a link a chatbox is going to open, i can have a lots of chatbox open.

How can i set a margin-right for only the first chatbox load ?

```
    $('.chat_user').live('click',function(){
        var substr = $(this).attr('alt').split('|');
        var user_id = substr[0];
        var user_name = substr[1];

        //check if a windows is already open with this user first!
        if($('div[title="'+user_id+'"]').length > 0){                   
            //alert('You\'re already chatting with him/her!');
        }else{
            PopupChat(user_id,user_name,1);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but jQuery's [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method was deprecated in 1.7 (2011) and removed entirely in 1.9 (Jan 2013), in favor of [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery First()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$('div[title="'+user_id+'"]').first().css({"margin-right", "10px"});
```

Comment: I hvae to put this code in the jquery i wrote above or in a separate code ? Thanks

Comment: You can put it in the PopupChat function or right after the call to PopupChat.  The css solution from Ohohorion is also viable.

Answer (score 0):

CSS only solution (this being styling issue) is to use [:first-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)
e.g:

```
div:first-child {margin-right: 10px;}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UX9gS/1/) JSFiddle to show in practice

EDIT: There are no need to check if the window is open before CSS starts working. CSS works always on items it is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should check if a window is open after that we will have to add the css ?